Schengen visa: cost of travelling and living during the applicant's stay
I'm applying for a Schengen visa to visit Greece as an Indian student to attend a conference. I specifically have doubt with question 32, which states:
"cost of travelling and living during the applicant's stay is covered"
Since I'm a student, all of my expenses will be taken care of by my parents. Which option should I choose then?

There is an ‘Other - please specify’ option IIRC

Your parents are your sponsor, you would be using your parents documents to back that claim.

There are 3 possible answers in this question.

"by the applicant himself/herself" (it is when you pay for yourself)
"by a sponsor (host, company, organisation)" (which is not your case)
"other (please specify):"

I would choose "other (please specify):" and explain that it is my parents.

Remember that it means you need to provide financial evidence for both yourself and your parents.

And possibly proof of the relationship
